# plenty of chance or plenty of chances

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to say 'plenty of chance' rather than 'plenty of chances' or are they both acceptable? You certainly wouldn't say 'many chance' but 'many chances'. Is there something about the phrase 'plenty of' or is it that the word 'chance' can be used to mean more than one opportunity, thus intrinsically denoting a plurality of concept? Can anyone explain the correct usage?

Comment: I'm AmE and would say "plenty of chance*s*". But maybe those BrEs would allow "plenty of chance" since they are (generally) more comfortable with mass nouns. I'm interested to see.

Comment: Google Books claims 1290 written instances of [*haven't had chance*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hypothetical+wishes%22#tbm=bks&q=%22haven%27t+had+chance%22) (without the article), but it should be noted that there are far more instances of *haven't had **a** chance*. Bear in mind that these are *written* contexts - if pedantic grammarians were to think the article *must* be present (I've no idea if they do or not) that wouldn't necessarily affect usage in *spoken* contexts so much. In the real (non-pedantic) world, both usages are perfectly normal.

Comment: plenty of chances, a countable noun but plenty of money or coffee nouns (uncountable).Chance (uncountable) and chance (countable) have two different meanings. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/chance_1   That said, the uncountable meaning here would not work in my opinion or as chance would have it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The problem with google is that it is inert and not a thinking person. /haven't had chance/ is not grammatical in English. /haven't had a chance or the chance/ is grammatical.

Comment: From what I can tell, the question is *not* about the use of *chance* as a mass noun generally. It's about the appearance of *chance* after *plenty of* and whether or not there is a convention of saying things like "I've given you plenty of chance, but now it's over!" Here's an Ngram, FWIW: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plenty+of+chance%2C+plenty+of+chances&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @Lambie: "Not grammatical in English"? Don't be silly! It's used daily by millions of people. Language is now covered by (descriptive) linguists, not (pedantic Victorian) grammarians.

Comment: ...consider [*(He) will have chance enough (to do something)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22will+have+chance+enough%22). Dozens of hits for that in Google Books, but nary a one for the same with ***a** chance*.

Comment: @fumble fingers To say "haven't had chance" sounds like Thanks God as used by non-native speakers of English. It is not about being pedantic, it is about sounding natural and I have never ever in all my born days heard: /haven't had chance/ without an "a" or a "the". In fact, the fact you claim it is so common is quite funny but it makes my ear crawl (joke). Are  you a native speaker of English??

Comment: @Lambie: I'm very definitely a native speaker! Not an English teacher, but I've got a degree in "Eng Lang & Lit", and I have several friends who *do* teach English for a living. And since the advent of Google Internet/Books, none of them will take bets with me if we disagree over which of two possible usages is more common. I don't have any real interest in the concept of "grammatically correct", but I'm better than most at guessing what usages are more common *before* confirming the situation online. Maybe there's something of a US/UK divide on this one (BrE is often more flexible today).

Comment: @fumblefingers  I'm sorry but the last time I "looked" a linguist relies on both learned knowledge and experiential knowledge. Like I said, google books is not proof of anything. Millions say: Thanks God, and I am sure it is out there. I have taught English (in a former life) and "haven't had chance" just does not sound like English. Yesterday, someone was arguing with me about "lock a deal"; as opposed to "lock-in or lock in a deal". You don't GET IT. I am not referring to grammatically correct at all.

Comment: @Lambie: I dispute the idea that "millions" say *Thanks God* - in fact, it seems to me quite possible that *no* native speakers say that (though I can't rule out some quirky US regional dialect). My degree also included linguistics, btw. And to the extent that linguists have a concept of "grammatical rules", these are almost exclusively derived from analysis of the forms people actually *use* (or identify as "acceptable"). Notions of grammaticality based on what Victorian Latin-versed pedagogues thought have no real relevance to linguistics today.

Comment: There's a difference between grammatically correct and something that is unidiomatic in any register. And then there is "deposition speak" (another issue). I would argue that "haven't had luck" is idiomatic whereas "haven't had chance" sounds like a typical Slavic (for example) mistake in English....I confirm usage by my own ear/experience (as a English teacher, linguist and translator). I am always "listening"....

Comment: Millions of Spanish speakers who have English as a second language say Thanks, God. It is a typical mistake. Like the French saying in English all the time: I have gone for I went mistakenly translating: Je suis allé as I HAVE gone.

Comment: @Lambie: Well, they do reckon within a generation there will be more Americans whose native tongue is Spanish rather than English, so presumably in time the remaining US Anglophones will come to accept *Thanks God!* as "natural". Spanish doesn't have that much influence on BrE though. Maybe some similar principle is involved with *haven't had luck*, which seems at least *slightly* "unusual" to me (but I'm quite happy with *haven't had **any** luck*, which according to Google Books is at least a dozen times more common).

Comment: @fumblefingers Playing google books: haven't had chance=1,300 hits;haven't had a chance=102,000 hits;haven't had the chance=15,900 hits. It used to be that basically every word in a novel was proofread by human eyes. Nowadays, I suppose that is no longer the case. I would argue that in the first 20 hits or so of /haven't had chance/ is a proofing error I would argue. Actually, I see a lot of this type of mistake in books today.

Comment: Of course, haven't had ANY luck is more common! Of course. But haven't had luck without any does not sound as weird as: /haven't had chance/

Answer (score 1):

"Luck" has a few definitions - one is "the quantity of luck" and the other is "the abstract concept of luckiness in general".

One of the meanings of "Chance" is synonymous with the "abstract concept of luckiness in general".  (As in "games of chance").  Another meaning is "opportunity".

However, there is no meaning of "chance" which is synonymous with "the quantity of luck".

So, to use some golfing examples (Golf is a luck-heavy sport) you could say "With a bit more luck, I can get this hole in 3 shots" but you **can't** say "With a bit more chance, I can get this hole in 3 shots".

You could say "I've got a chance to get this hole in 3 shots.", if, say, you'd been lucky so far and needed a little bit more luck to make the last shot.

"Plenty of luck" is using the "quantity of luck" meaning, and so you cannot subsitute the word "chance".  You **can** say "chances", as that means "opportunities".

Comment: What you say makes perfect sense. plenty of means a large quantity of [countable things] or large quantity of [uncountable things]. The uncountable meaning of chance does  not work here.

Comment: Playing google books: haven't had chance=1,300 hits;haven't had a chance=102,000 hits;haven't had the chance=15,900 hits. It used to be that basically every word in a novel was proofread by human eyes. Nowadays, I suppose that is no longer the case. I would argue that in the first 20 hits or so of: haven't had chance is a proofing oversight...